# From python to call a Matlab function containing pause, how to input something to keep the program running like how it works in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, plot, scatter

I want to use python to call a self-defined Matlab function which contains pause. The program does pause, but I don't know how to let it continue.

Here is a simple testing code to show my problem. To be more specific, when 'test1' appear and the program paused, what can I do to make it print 'test2'?

In Python:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.addpath('J:\EVresearch\Version2\Matlab',nargout=0)
eng.testing170319(nargout=0)
```

In Matlab:

```
function testing170319()
disp('test1')
pause
disp('test2')
```